# PHP PhantomJS get page contents after JavaScript reload

Tags: javascript, php, php-phantomjs

I am trying to get the contents of [this page](https://www.alarabiya.net/.mrss/ar.xml) with [php-phantomjs](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs). After some digging, I noticed that this page first loads this JavaScript code:

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays) { // Local function for setting a value of a cookie
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires=" + exdate.toGMTString()) + ";path=/";
}
function getHostUri() {
    var loc = document.location;
    return loc.toString();
}
setCookie('YPF8827340282Jdskjhfiw_928937459182JAX666', '[request_ip_addr]', 10);
try {  
    location.reload(true);  
} catch (err1) {  
    try {  
        location.reload();  
    } catch (err2) {  
        location.href = getHostUri();  
    }  
}
```

Which clearly sets a cookie with my IP address, then reloads the page.

I am executing the request from my PHP server this way:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;

$client = Client::getInstance();
$client->getEngine()
        ->debug(true)
        ->addOption("--cookies-file='/cookies.txt'");

$request = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest();
$response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();

$request->setMethod('GET');
$request->setUrl('https://www.alarabiya.net/.mrss/ar.xml');

$client->send($request, $response);

var_dump($client->getLog());

if ($response->getStatus() === 200) {
    echo $response->getContent();
} else {
    echo 'Error loading data';
}
```

Which is returning an empty page, a `var_dump($response->getContent())` show that it is *NULL*.

I think that PhantomJS is not executing the `location.reload()` call, if this is the case can someone tell me how to make follow this reload? Or what might be the problem causing this?

**EDIT**: The script is working fine when using this link 'http://jonnyw.me' mentioned in the basic usage guide.

Answer (score 0):

$request->setDelay(3);
delay 3s to exe js